# how to create google cloud storage account without paying any charge

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am try to create account on google cloud storage but in trial version it need credit card or my personal information but I do not want to reveal my personal information please suggest me a link or a way so that I can efficiently create my account on google cloud storage without any charges.

Answer (score 2):

Free storage is not a feature of Google Cloud Storage.

You may be interested in Google's consumer-facing storage product, Google Drive, which does have a free tier, or in App Engine, which provides up to 1 GB per day of free storage.